# Mobx State Tree Flow. How to Know when it's done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am using mobx state tree and mobx for UI Stuff.

Now when I save something to db, after the request is done I want to update the ui(ie my mobx state).

I need to know when the flow is finished.

```
  myFlow: flow(function* () {
          // do stuff here.
    }),
```

now I see that a promise is returned, so I thought of just doing

```
myFlow.then()
```

which works but I am wondering if this is the property way or if there is another way to do this(async/await? or some internal thing that flow has?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a flow returns a promise, so any promise waiting mechanism works: `.then`, `await`, or `yield` inside another `flow`. If you want to render the state of the flow, take a look at `mobxUtils.fromPromise(promise).case(....)` of the mobx-utils package

Comment: What do you mean render the state of the flow? Also if I am using Axios and yield it. do I return it's response and that gets wrapped in a promise by "flow"?

Comment: A flow is a promise in itself, so if you want render it's state during the promise transitions, the above util comes in handy.

Comment: You can yield anything that returns a promise and flow will await it.

Comment: but do I have to await the actual flow method? I want to do stuff after myFlow is called and finished. I want to either capture an error and update the UI or capture the success and update the UI but I want to do it outside of the flow call.

Comment: any flow method returns a promise. So you can await that, then it, etc: `myObject.myFlow().then(() => { console.log('done!') }`

Answer (score 1):

Inside generator you can call some another action at the end.

In example below I call `thisIsWhatYouNeed` function. This function will be called when generator ends.

```
myFlow: flow(function* () {        
  try {
    const response = yield fetch('your URL here');
    const data = yield response.json()

    // here you can call another action
    self.thisIsWhatYouNeed(data);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error happens');
  }
})

thisIsWhatYouNeed(data) {
  // here you have your data and know that flow is finished
  console.log('generator already finished');
}
```